# Improving canvas performance for a color average animation

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I'm trying to create a canvas project inspired by [this gif](https://24.media.tumblr.com/3705ecdfc18c46fb34889de6c3fef09b/tumblr_n69ezpTLsg1rpco88o1_400.gif) where colors of an image are averaged and animated.

Thus far I have all of the functionality working but it only performs well with a large cell size.

My current thinking is that it's all of the `.fillRect`s that are causing the issue because rendering is expensive.

Am I correct in thinking this? Is there any way to chain these `fillRect`s together and use one render each iteration like one would with paths as opposed to a new render for each `fillRect`?

Other performance improvements are welcome as well.

```js
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    pixelInterval = 5, // Rather than inspect every single pixel in the image inspect every 5th pixel
    img = document.getElementById("imageToBeUsed"), // The image to be averaged
    cellSize = 100, // The size of square to average the color
    cw, // Canvas width
    ch; // Canvas height

var cellCanvas = document.getElementById("cellCanvas"),
    cellContext = cellCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Use a CORS proxy to allow the image to be used
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = "https://crossorigin.me/" + img.src;
img.onload = function() {
  // Once the CORS enabled image loads, do our work
  newImg(img);
  animateColorAvg();
}


// Updates the image to be used
function newImg(imgElem) {
  img = imgElem;
  
  // Set the height and width of the canvas elements to that of the image
  cw = imgCanvas.width = cellCanvas.width = img.naturalWidth || img.offsetWidth || img.width;
  ch = imgCanvas.height = cellCanvas.height = img.naturalHeight || img.offsetHeight || img.height;
  
  // Draw the image to our hidden canvas for calculations
  imgContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Animate the movement of the cells
var offset = 0,
    playSpeed = 0, // Determines how often the canvas is updated
   lastTime = Date.now();

function animateColorAvg() {
  if(Date.now() - lastTime > playSpeed) {
  lastTime = Date.now();
    
    offset += 5;
    if(offset >= cellSize)
      offset = 0;
  
    gridifyAvgColors(offset);
 }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animateColorAvg);
}

// Creates a grid of average colors of the current image
function gridifyAvgColors(cellOffset) {
  var numXCells = Math.ceil(cw / cellSize),
      numYCells = Math.ceil(ch / cellSize);
  
  // Start at the bottom right, go to top left
  for(var i = numXCells; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(var j = numYCells; j >= 0; j--) {
      var x = i * cellSize - cellSize + cellOffset,
          y = j * cellSize - cellSize + cellOffset,
          color = getAvgColorAsRGB(x, y);
      
      cellContext.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color.r + ", " + color.g + ", " + color.b + ")";
      cellContext.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
    }
  }
}

// Gets the average color of the requested area
function getAvgColorAsRGB(startX, startY) {
  // Check to see if a cell placed at this location covers any part of the image
  if(!(  (startX < cw
       && startY < ch)
      || (startX + cellSize >= 0
       && startY + cellSize >= 0)
     ))
     return; // Don't calculate anything because it's not covering a part of the image
  
  var cellSizeX = cellSize,
      cellSizeY = cellSize;
  
  // Account for negative starting values that still cover a part of the image
  if(startX < 0) {
    cellSizeX = 0 - startX;
    startX = 0;
  }
  if(startY < 0) {
    cellSizeY = 0 - startY;
    startY = 0;
  }
  
  // Account for values that go outside of the image
  if(startX + cellSizeX > cw && startX != cw)
    cellSizeX = cw - startX;
  if(startY + cellSizeY > ch && startY != ch)
    cellSizeY = ch - startY;
  
  var rgb = { r:0, g:0, b:0 },
      count = 0,
      i = -4,
      data, length;

  try {
    data = imgContext.getImageData(startX, startY, cellSizeX, cellSizeY);
  } catch(e) {
    // Catch errors - usually due to cross domain security issues
    console.log(e);
    return;
  }

  data = data.data;
  length = data.length;
  while ((i += pixelInterval * 4) < length) {
    count++;
    rgb.r += data[i];
    rgb.g += data[i + 1];
    rgb.b += data[i + 2];
  }
  
  // Round the number values
  rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);
  rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);
  rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);

  return rgb;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cellCanvas"></canvas>
<img id="imageToBeUsed" src="http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2013/pets/news/130304/kitten-3-600.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Can you please update your examples? I think the image is broken

Comment: @NextLocal It works for me in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a suggestion by a friend, I realized it wasn't the `.fillRect` that was causing the performance issue, but rather the looped `imgContext.getImageData()`. I originally thought it wasn't this because it seemed to work fine with large cells (it seems dumb to think that now).

After changing to a single `getImageData()` and converting the rest of the calculations to match, it now performs flawlessly!

```js
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    pixelInterval = 5, // Rather than inspect every single pixel in the image inspect every 5^2 pixel
    img = document.getElementById("imageToBeUsed"), // The image to be averaged
    cellSize = 20, // The size of square to average the color
    cw, // Canvas width
    ch; // Canvas height

var cellCanvas = document.getElementById("cellCanvas"),
    cellContext = cellCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Use a CORS proxy to allow the image to be used
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = "https://crossorigin.me/" + img.src;
img.onload = function() {
  // Once the CORS enabled image loads, do our work
  newImg(img);
  animateColorAvg();
}

var data; // A 1D array

var numXCells,
    numYCells;

// Updates the image to be used
function newImg(imgElem) {
  img = imgElem;
  
  // Set the height and width of the canvas elements to that of the image
  cw = imgCanvas.width = cellCanvas.width = img.naturalWidth || img.offsetWidth || img.width;
  ch = imgCanvas.height = cellCanvas.height = img.naturalHeight || img.offsetHeight || img.height;
  
  // Draw the image to our hidden canvas for calculations
  imgContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
  // Set the image data
  try {
    data = imgContext.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch);
  } catch(e) {
    // Catch errors - usually due to cross domain security issues
    console.log(e);
    return;
  }

  data = data.data;
}

// Animate the movement of the cells
var offset = -5,
    playSpeed = 1000, // Determines how often the canvas is updated
    lastTime = Date.now();

function animateColorAvg() {
  //if(Date.now() - lastTime > playSpeed) {
  lastTime = Date.now();
    
    offset += 5;
    if(offset >= cellSize)
      offset = 0;
  
    gridifyAvgColors(offset);
  //}

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animateColorAvg);
}

// Creates a grid of average colors of the current image
function gridifyAvgColors(cellOffset) {
  numXCells = Math.ceil(cw / cellSize);
  numYCells = Math.ceil(ch / cellSize);
  
  // Start at the bottom right, go to top left
  for(var i = numXCells; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(var j = numYCells; j >= 0; j--) {
      var x = i * cellSize - cellSize + cellOffset,
          y = j * cellSize - cellSize + cellOffset,
          color = getAvgColorAsRGB(x, y);
      
      cellContext.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color.r + ", " + color.g + ", " + color.b + ")";
      cellContext.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
    }
  }
}

// Gets the average color of the requested area
function getAvgColorAsRGB(startX, startY) {
 var rgb = { r:0, g:0, b:0 };
  
  // Check to see if a cell placed at this location covers any part of the image
  if(!(  (startX < cw
       && startY < ch)
      || (startX + cellSize >= 0
       && startY + cellSize >= 0)
  )) 
   return rgb; // Don't calculate anything because it's not covering a part of the image
  
  var cellSizeX = cellSize,
      cellSizeY = cellSize;
  
  // Account for negative starting values that still cover a part of the image
  if(startX < 0) {
    cellSizeX = 0 - startX;
    startX = 0;
  }
  if(startY < 0) {
    cellSizeY = 0 - startY;
    startY = 0;
  }
  
  // Account for values that go outside of the image
  if(startX + cellSizeX > cw && startX != cw)
    cellSizeX = cw - startX;
  if(startY + cellSizeY > ch && startY != ch)
    cellSizeY = ch - startY;
  
  var count = 0;
      
  for(var j = startY; j < startY + cellSizeY; j += pixelInterval) { 
   for(var i = startX; i < startX + cellSizeX; i += pixelInterval) { // Do this second for lookup perf reasons
      count++;
      var index = (i + j * numXCells * cellSize) * 4;
      rgb.r += data[index];
      rgb.g += data[index + 1];
      rgb.b += data[index + 2];
    }
  }
  
  // Round the number values
  rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);
  rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);
  rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);

  return rgb;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cellCanvas"></canvas>
<img id="imageToBeUsed" src="http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2013/pets/news/130304/kitten-3-600.jpg"/>
```

P.S. There's no way to chain `.fillRect`s, but that likely isn't the cause of the performance issue.

Comment: Here's the [final result](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/eJWEvg)